# getting average mean for each period in a ffdf object in R

Tags: r, mean, ff

I have an ffdf object called 'group1' that has a million rows of data that looks like this:

```
       Location                  DateandTime   Reading     Group
1             1          01/01/2012 00:00:00     0.8           1   
2             1          01/01/2012 00:30:00     0.4           1  
3             1          01/01/2012 01:00:00     0.7           1   
4             1          01/01/2012 01:30:00     0.2           1
```

I'm trying to get an average 'Reading' and standard deviation for each 'DateandTime' and create a new df to look something like this:

```
                      DateTime     mean     sd
1          01/01/2012 00:00:00     0.8     .2        
2          01/01/2012 00:30:00     0.5     .5        
3          01/01/2012 01:00:00     0.2     .3         
4          01/01/2012 01:30:00     0.8     .8
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `dplyr` package

```
    library(dplyr)
    group1.stat <- group1 %>% 
      select(DateandTime, Reading) %>% 
      group_by(DateandTime) %>% 
      summarise_each(funs(mean = mean(., na.rm = TRUE), sd = sd(., na.rm = TRUE)))
    group1.stat
```

Comment: i get the following error: Error in UseMethod("select_") : 
  no applicable method for 'select_' applied to an object of class "ffdf"

Comment: Is there a method for making this work specifically for ffdf objects?

Comment: `dplyr` works with data frame. You need to convert your ffdf objects to data.frame using `as.data.frame`

Answer (score 0):

This `dplyr` approach will also work:

```
library(dplyr)

newdf <- group1 %>% 
  group_by(DateandTime) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(Reading), sd = sd(Reading))
```

Comment: I get the following error: Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : 
  no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "ffdf"

Comment: Is there a method for making this work specifically for ffdf objects?